# my rust analyzer don't work on emacs 27

Tags: lsp, rust

I recently installed the latest version of emacs and Rust-analyzer, and downloaded the lsp-mode package as well, but when I activate the rust-analyzer with the "lsp" command it simply returns an error saying that the rust-analyzer keep loading

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate about what you did - provide a recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). And set `debug-on-error` to non-nil and show the backtrace when the error is raised. The question isn't clear, so far - we have to guess what you did and what you saw at each step.

Answer (score 2):

rust-analyzer can take a while to index and load a project. You should still be fine, even if the text in the minibuffer doesn't immediately change. Try using e.g. the auto completion and see if it works.

If you want to test a prebuilt config, I recently written [a guide](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/) to setup Emacs for Rust and it has a [repo](https://github.com/rksm/emacs-rust-config) with an example config that you can run as-is. This was tested with Emacs 27.1, MacOS, Win 10, and Ubuntu.